# Keys with same name with multiple Values in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am practicing myself in python online and have come across this question.

https://www.testdome.com/questions/python/file-owners/11846?visibility=1&skillId=9

I dont know how to solve this. When I interchange the Key and Value and I am getting the output with only unique Key-value pairs as below

```
{'Stan': 'Code.py', 'Randy': 'Input.txt'}
```

Kindly suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: You can't have a duplicate key in a `dict`, this is why you get this output. I really think giving you the answer wouldn't be beneficial for you. Also, provide your not working code so we can guide you in solving it yourself.

Comment: check out the Werkzeug `MultiDict` datastructure for reference: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put the value in the list for "Randy", as in dictionary we can't have multiple keys of same name. Here is the solution for the same,

```
class FileOwners:

    @staticmethod
    def group_by_owners(files):
        d={}
        for i in files:
           if files[i] in d:
            d[files[i]].append(i)
           else:
            d[files[i]]=[i]
        return d

files = {
    'Input.txt': 'Randy',
    'Code.py': 'Stan',
    'Output.txt': 'Randy'
}
print(FileOwners.group_by_owners(files))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the same key in a dict. For your example, use owner as key and the value will be a list of files.

Something like this:

```
class FileOwners:

@staticmethod
def group_by_owners(files):
    result = {}
    for _f in list(files.keys()):
        if not files[_f] in result.keys():
            result[files[_f]] = []
        result[files[_f]].append(_f)
    return result

files = {
    'Input.txt': 'Randy',
    'Code.py': 'Stan',
    'Output.txt': 'Randy'
}
print(FileOwners.group_by_owners(files))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: instead of using a single item as the contents of the dict, use a list. Then, using a `for` loop, gradually populate that list with items:

```
output = {}
for key, value in files.items():
    if value in output:
        output[value].append(key)
    else:
        output[value] = [key]
return output
```

You can see here that we first create a new dictionary, `output`, and then we put the key-value pairs from `files` into `output` as value-key.

The key here is that each value of `output` is a *list*, not just a single item. That's why we check if the value already exists in `output` before adding it: if it does, then we just add the new `key` to the list. If not, we create a new list, with just one element: `key`.

A `dict` can't have duplicate keys, which is why when you just interchange a dict (e.g. `output = {val:key for key, val in files.items()}`) the code doesn't work as intended. The first value for `Randy` gets overwritten by the second value for `Randy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class FileOwners:

    @staticmethod
    def group_by_owners(files):
        d = defaultdict(list)
        for k, v in files.items():
            d[v].append(k)
        return dict(d)

files = {
    'Input.txt': 'Randy',
    'Code.py': 'Stan',
    'Output.txt': 'Randy'
}
print(FileOwners.group_by_owners(files))

# {'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
```